# How to pass querysets or the context dictronary from one view to another view

Tags: python, django

I need to pass a queryset from one view to another. I read I could use sessions to archive this, but I have no clou how this works. In my first view, I filter by some values and save the values in a variable (type : queryset). I need this queryset in another view to display the results on another template.

I would be appreciate for any bit of help.

Comment: Why not separate out the function that returns the value and you can call the function from any number of places you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you code an short example? I am not able to try it myself right now  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queryset in a view and save it in the session so that you can use same queryset results in some other view. But i am not sure why you need to do this. Here is an example.

```
def first_view(request):
   cards = Card.objects.all()
   request.session['cards'] = cards

def second_view(request):
   cards = request.session['cards']
   # you can use the cards queryset to render in a template
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I need to do it this way, because I filter through my table using some user input. But I need to display the filtered queryset on several other sides and my first idea to archive this was to grab my filtered queryset on another view to display them im those html template. Maybe you know a better way to do this ? Could I just pass my queryset to more then one HTML template? And when I tried what you suggested, I got this error: "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable".